# Python 3 - Problemas com data de Nascimento

Tags: python-3.x

Boa noite, o código a baixo em python3 deve retornar uma valor de mensalidade de acordo com a idade do cliente, usei o modulo time para obter a idade do cliente quando ele informar seu ano de nascimento, pensando na possibilidade do usuário informar um ano de nascimento superior o atual, coloquei o seguinte retorno:

```
"elif idade < 0:
   print('##ERRO## INFORME ANO VALIDO!') "
```

Porem ele retorno o valor de R$50.00...

Alguém pode oferecer uma ajuda??

[image: Terminal com a demonstração do código em execução]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Uma observação a se fazer: método usado para calcular a idade da pessoa não esta correto, pois deve fazer a verificação completa com o dia e mês do nascimento.

Em sua condição, você começa verificando se a idade é igual ou menor que 18.

```
if idade <= 18:
```

Ai aonde esta o problema, você deve verificar também se idade é maior que 0.

```
if idade >= 0 and idade <= 18:
```

> Veja funcionando no [repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/SteepLankyHoneycreeper)

Comment: Obrigado, funcionou, mais uma sendo traído pelos pequenos detalhes.. \m/

Answer (score -1):

Na linha 11 deveria estar:

`if(idade >= 0 and idade <= 18):`

Na linha 21:

`else:`